# Is it possible to have functions generated from template as f() and f<T>()?

Tags: c++, c++11

Is it possible to have functions generated from template as `f()` and `f<T>()` ?

I want to call f most of the time with the type specified, such as:

```
f<string>();
f<int>();
```

but I also need to call it like this:

```
f();
```

and the type when not specified it should be string. Is this possible?

Comment: What do you expect `f()` to mean then?

Comment: @JanHudec: `f<std::string>()` obviously.

Comment: @MSalters: You are right. Reading fail, obviously.

Answer (score 9):

```
template <typename T>
void f() { ... }

void f() { f<string>(); }
```

Comment: Won't be generated from template, which does matter. E.g. the template may be a friend, but the overload will not be.

Comment: True, but since the overload simply calls the template, that should not matter. You can probably construct a case where it does, but whether that case is likely to occur in real-world programming is a different question.

Answer (score 8):

You can give default type for template arguments:

```
template<class T=std::string>
foo()
```

Note: If you give default argument to template class, you must declare the default version with `Foo<>`. This is not necessary when calling templated functions; You can call the default version without angle brackets: `foo()`

Another note: This works for functions because of template argument deduction. Quote from the standard (January 2012 draft §14.8.2.5) emphasis mine:

> The resulting substituted and adjusted function type is used as the
>   type of the function template for template argument deduction. **If a
>   template argument has not been deduced, its default template argument,
>   if any, is used**. [ Example:

```
template <class T, class U = double>
void f(T t = 0, U u = 0);
void g() {
    f(1, ’c’);     //f<int,char>(1,’c’)
    f(1);          //f<int,double>(1,0)
    f();           //error: T cannot be deduced
    f<int>();      //f<int,double>(0,0)
    f<int,char>(); //f<int,char>(0,0)
}
```

Comment: Others said I can't do that!

Comment: I'd like to know why they said so. This simple example works: http://ideone.com/M8ERrH

Comment: Note that this is only allowed since C++11.

Comment: I've added a quote from the standard.

Answer (score 2):

```
#include <string>

template <typename T=std::string>
void f() {}

int main()
{
  f();
}
```

Comment: But then you'd still have to use `f<>()` IIRC.

Comment: Yes but when calling it without type specified will I have to say f<>(); ? That is, will I have to include the angle brackets?